# Problem with Greek title

Tags: titles, unicode, greek, amsart

I'm having a problem writing a paper in Greek, using `amsart`.

I'm using the packages `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}` and `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` and am able to write Greek & English throughout the paper without problem.

However when I write Greek at the title I get weird characters like:

[image]

instead of only capital letters.

My code is

```
\begin{document}

\title{τυχαιος τιτλος}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated!

EDIT: Sample code of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
```

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Θεώρημα}[section]
\newtheorem{problem}{Πρόβλημα}[section]
\newtheorem{identity}{Ταυτότητα}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Πρόταση}[section]
\newtheorem{conclusion}{Πόρισμα}[section]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Άσκηση}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Ορισμός}
\newtheorem{example}{Παράδειγμα}[section]
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\abs}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgIbg.png){\lvert#1\rvert}

\newcommand{\blankbox}[2]{%
  \parbox{\columnwidth}{\centering
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
    \fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[#2]{\hspace{#1}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Δοκιμαστικος τιτλος}

\author{Αρθρογραφος}

\address{Τμήμα Μαθηματικών}

% \date{}

\begin{abstract}
Περιληψη
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section*{}

\begin{proposition}
Τυχαία Πρόταση
\end{proposition}

\begin{proof}
Η απόδειξη παραλείπεται.
\end{proof}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem {A} Ιστότοπος \selectlanguage{english} \textit{mathematica.gr}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Sverre thanks, but the paper I have prepared is 8 pages long full of Mathematics and the only problem I'm having is with the title in Greek, so I don't see why I should post the whole code.

Comment: Correct, you shouldn't post all of your code, but a [minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Sverre edited.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to how `amsart` uppercases the title. You solve it by adding

```
\usepackage{textcase}
```

that will use the safer `\MakeTextUppercase` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{textcase}

\begin{document}
\title{τυχαιος τιτλος}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It won't work with `utf8x`, though.

[image]

If you want to use `utf8x`, you need to prerender some characters, in this specific case

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{textcase}

\PrerenderUnicode{τ}
\PrerenderUnicode{υ}
\PrerenderUnicode{χ}
\PrerenderUnicode{α}
\PrerenderUnicode{ι}
\PrerenderUnicode{ο}
\PrerenderUnicode{ς}
\PrerenderUnicode{λ}

\begin{document}
\title{τυχαιος τιτλος}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I replaced utf8x with utf8 since I saw it is a much safer option. I also didn't need to use the \MakeTextUppercase command, for a weird reason.

Comment: @Nickolas With `\usepackage{textcase}` the `\MakeTextUppercase` command will be used implicitly, you don't need it in your document.

Comment: Many Thanks for the clarification and for your answer!